# How to generate random number and export it as JSON?

Tags: java, json

I was planning to generate a random number and export it as JSON using `json-simple`. I have the following code

```
public class Main implements JSONAware{

    private final int data;

    public Main(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }


    public String toJSONString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append("[");

        sb.append(data);

        sb.append("]");
        sb.append(",");


        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JSONArray da = new JSONArray();


        Random generator = new Random();
        int [][] grid;

        grid = new int[128][14];

        for (int row = 0; row < 128; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 14; col++){
                grid[row][col] = generator.nextInt(100);
//                da.add("%d",grid[row][col]);
                da.add(grid[row][col]);
            }
//            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(da);

    }
```

This prints as following:

`[9,62,6,60,29,28,59,56,67,61,53,23,22,31,15,96,94,85,65,94,15,7,91,...]`

but I was trying to print it as

```
[9,62,6,60,29,28,59,56,67,61,53,23,22,31,15,96,94,85,65,94,15,7,91,...],
[68,48,40,44,47,85,8,43,17,78,35,7,77,26,80,34,19,47,17,0,59,5,79,...],
.
.
.
```

can anyone tell me how would I split the row from column?

Comment: You are adding grid values to same array `da` for each row. But in example, you are printing two different arrays. I would suggest you to create `JSONArray` object for each row. Then add the arrays to the `JSONObject`

Comment: @Utkarsh Could you tell me how I do that, you mean to say i have to create `128` rows. How would i create new objects like that?

Comment: if you print out grid, it will show as you wanted

Comment: @khuderm doesn't do that, just prints out like this `[[I@4d7e1886,[I@4d7e1886,[I@4d7e1886,[I@4d7e1886,...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, You want 128 rows to be separate JsonArray i.e. 1 row = 1 JsonArray.
For that you could do :

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

    Random generator = new Random();
    int [][] grid;

    grid = new int[128][14];

    for (int row = 0; row < 128; row++){
        JSONArray da = new JSONArray();
        for (int col = 0; col < 14; col++){
            grid[row][col] = generator.nextInt(100);
            da.add(grid[row][col]);
        }
        jArray.add(da);
    }
    System.out.println(jArray);

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @akshay just a sidenote : with your level of knowledge you should'nt jump ahead and do complex stuff like JSON serialization / deserialization ... you need to learn programming basics first. We all want to conquer the world but everyone who refused to start small and from the beginning ... failed. Do a beginners' tutorial, exercise with small projects and go up from there; JSON communication may be YEARS down the road ...

Comment: @specializt thank you for the advice, I don t usually do Java and do more of the programming in Python and Matlab. I am in need of this because the Matlab is more compatible with Java rather than Python. So I hope you understand why I would need to learn this :)

Comment: @akshay Matlab has nothing to do with programming ... just saying

Answer (score 0):

Just use Json api provided with javaee. And it will be easily accomplished. You will not need to create any `jsonToString(...)`.

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
...
public static void main(String ...args) {

    JsonObjectBuilder jsonBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();

    Random generator = new Random();
    int[][] grid;

    grid = new int[128][14];

    for (int row = 0; row < 128; row++) {
        JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (int col = 0; col < 14; col++) {
            grid[row][col] = generator.nextInt(100);
            arrayBuilder.add(grid[row][col]);
        }
        jsonBuilder.add(Integer.toString(row), arrayBuilder.build());
    }
    JsonObject json = jsonBuilder.build();

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

**Well if you dont want to use javaee's json api**, In your code :

```
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

    Random generator = new Random();
    int [][] grid;

    grid = new int[128][14];

    for (int row = 0; row < 128; row++){
        JSONArray da = new JSONArray();
        for (int col = 0; col < 14; col++){
            grid[row][col] = generator.nextInt(100);
            da.add(grid[row][col]);
        }
        obj.put(Integer.toString(row), da);
    }
    System.out.println(obj);
```